# Do not mark emails as read/seen using imap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imap

In my rails application I have a rake task that reads emails using imap. The emails are read and are marked as read/seen. I do not want to mark the emails as read/seen. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to supply some code. What's your current implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/net/1.9.2/Net/IMAP/FetchData

When you fetch the email, you get the flags.  You want to remove the \Seen flag.